# Using ko.utils.arrayForEach to select check boxes in the table generated by knockout foreach binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout foreach binding to generate a table with the help of following code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: queryData">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" /></td>
<td data-bind="text: id"></td>
<td data-bind="text: EN"></td>
<td data-bind="text: CN"></td>
<td data-bind="text: PN"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Values for columns id, EN, CN and PN are received from a PHP script in an AJAX response which is set to queryData observable array as following:

```
self.queryData($.parseJSON(data));
```

I have following observables defined:

```
this.queryData= ko.observableArray();
this.isChecked = ko.observable();
```

Once complete table is loaded I want an option to select all the checkboxes in the table with the help of ko.utils.arrayForEach using following code:

```
this.selectAll = function(){
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.queryData(),function(items){
self.isChecked(true);
});
};
```

I know that isChecked is not defined in the queryData observable array but I do want to run loop on all items inside queryData and set the isChecked to true.

Comment: What's your question? It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JeffMercado I am trying to implement a select all rows functionality which should set following to true for every row in a table which is generated using knockout foreach binding from server data: <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" /></td>

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
this.selectAll = function(){
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.queryData(),function(items){
items.isChecked(true); // `items` instead of `self` because you are looping here
});
};
```

Fiddle to your requirement check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/aco0qpbd/)

Best way will be using computed which is something similar you can find it  [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/AneL9/) using read/write